# Efficient LINQ Query for large dataset

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a LINQ query that run on datatable that has 5,00,000 plus records. This query returns me only one row but takes almost 30 seconds to run. This is my query

```
  var callDetailsForNodes = from records in dtRowForNode.Select().Select(dr =>
    new
    {
        caller1 = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(dr["F1"], dr["F2"]) < 0 ? dr["F1"] : dr["F2"],
        caller2 = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(dr["F1"], dr["F2"]) < 0 ? dr["F2"] : dr["F1"],
        time = dr["F3"],
        filters = dr.Field<string>("F9")
    }).Where(dr => (dtMin <= Convert.ToDateTime(dr.time)) && (dtMax >= Convert.ToDateTime(dr.time)) && (lstCallType.Contains(dr.filters))
             && (dtMinTime <= Convert.ToDateTime(dr.time).TimeOfDay) && (dtMaxTime >= Convert.ToDateTime(dr.time).TimeOfDay))
    .GroupBy(drg => new { drg.caller1, drg.caller2 })
    .Select(drg => new { drg.Key.caller1, drg.Key.caller2, count = drg.Count() }).AsEnumerable()
                                  where (records.caller1.ToString() == VerSelected || records.caller2.ToString() == VerSelected)
                                  select records;
```

Again i run a query to rearrange the data get it from above query as

```
 var callDetailsForNodes_ReArrange = from records in callDetailsForNodes.Select(r => new
        {
            caller1 = r.caller1.ToString() == VerSelected ? r.caller1 : r.caller2,
            caller2 = r.caller1.ToString() != VerSelected ? r.caller1 : r.caller2,
            count = r.count
        })
        select records;
```

Then i am just binding this collection to gridview. 
Is there any efficient way to query on such a large dataset

**Edit**

I have try to debug the programm step by step and find that this 2 queries actually runs fast and time is taken at the step when i add the result set of this query to ObservableCollection to bind it to gridview. Here  is the code

```
foreach (var callDetailsForNode_ReArrange in callDetailsForNodes_ReArrange)
        {

                _CallForNodes.Add(new CallForNodeData
                {
                    Caller1 = callDetailsForNode_ReArrange.caller1.ToString(),
                    Caller2 = callDetailsForNode_ReArrange.caller2.ToString(),
                    Count = callDetailsForNode_ReArrange.count
                });

        }
```

Here callDetailsForNodes_ReArrange has resultset count = 1

Comment: _" Is there any efficient way to query on such a large dataset"_ Yes, use a database!

Comment: Have you broken your query down to see which part is the slowest? E.g. you could stop after your first `Select` and call `ToList()`. Then add the `Where` and call `ToList()` etc. This would help you identify the part that is causing most slow down. However, as Tim says this should be done in a database.

Comment: I suspect you may be confused. Once you start iterating over the collection it then executes your query. `callDetailsForNodes` is just a query up until the point you cause it to execute. Adding 1 item to an `ObservableCollection` should not be slow.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that would help would be to convert dtMin, dtMax and dtMinTime before the call into the units of the data (dr.time).  Then you can get rid of the Convert.ToDateTime that is happening multiple times on each record.

Comment: where should i do it, in datatable itself or at the time i fetch it in code i.e time = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["F3"])

Comment: @RajeevKumar What you've put in your comment.

Comment: @RajeevKumar In your first select you set `time = dr["F3"]`. I think what Rawling is suggesting is you change this to `time = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["F3"])`. That way `time` is a date time and doesn't have to be converted multiple times in the `Where`.

Comment: @RajeevKumar, I meant where you setup dtMin etc.  Change their type to the same type as the datatable time then compare directly.  Then you do not have any per row conversion overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I have tidied up your query a little (although this won't make a massive amount of difference to performance, and there may be typos as I don't have VS to hand). From your edit it seems you are a little confused by deferred execution in LINQ. `callDetailsForNodes` does not represent your results - it is a query that will provide your results once it is executed.

If you have to do all this querying in process I suggest you add a `ToList` after the first select and run that in isolation. Then add `ToList` to the `Where` clause. Calling `ToList` will force your query to execute and you will see where the delays are.

One final note - you should pass your records directly to `ObservableCollection` constructor rather than calling `Add` for each item. Calling `Add` will (I think) cause the collection to raise a changed notification which is not a big deal for small lists but will slow things down for larger lists.

```
var callDetailsForNodes = dtRowForNode.AsEnumerable()
                              .Select(dr => new {
                                                    caller1 = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(dr["F1"], dr["F2"]) < 0 ? dr["F1"] : dr["F2"],
                                                    caller2 = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(dr["F1"], dr["F2"]) < 0 ? dr["F2"] : dr["F1"],
                                                    time = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["F3"]),
                                                    filters = dr.Field<string>("F9")})
                              .Where(dr => (dtMin <= dr.time) 
                                        && (dtMax >= dr.time) 
                                        && (lstCallType.Contains(dr.filters))
                                        && (dtMinTime <= dr.time.TimeOfDay) 
                                        && (dtMaxTime >= dr.time.TimeOfDay)
                                        && caller1 == VerSelected || caller2 == VerSelected))
                              .GroupBy(drg => new { drg.caller1, drg.caller2 })
                              .Select(drg => new { drg.Key.caller1, drg.Key.caller2, count = drg.Count());
```